# EF / Database Initializor / Order of Execution

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Julie Lermans course on Entity Framework in the Enterprise she creates a base context class that looks like this.

```
Public class BaseContext<Tcontext> : DBContext where Tcontext :DBContext
{
static BaseContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
}
Protected BaseContext()
:base("connectionStringName")
{}
}
```

which is used like this:

```
public class xxxContext : BaseContext<xxxContext>
{
public Field A { get;set;}
}
```

She then goes on to say, for database initialization in her repository would look like this

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<XXXXContext>())
using (var context = new xxxContext())
(
    Assert.AreEqual(0, context.Customers.Count()));
)
```

My question is:
In the last section of code (in this example), the Database.SetInitializer executes first, setting the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionas the initializer.  However, in the creation of the context, the static constructor of the base class would execute (Database.SetInitializer(null)) before the context is actually created.  By the time the code reaches context.Customers.Count()  - the initializer would be NULL, and the default initializer would then execute (CreateIfDatabaseNotExists).

Am I wrong? How does the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion get retained? Or does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, when you call `Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(<ANY_DatabaseInitializer>);`, the context's Initialization Strategy is registered or updated.

So yes, if you are accessing the TContext after setting the `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext>())', the TContext will set the Strategy to`NullDatabaseInitializer` in the static constructor. That will cause the latest migration code to remain without executed and there will exception for the mismatch.

Moover, Look at this link [Entity Framework Code First Web.config Initialization](http://www.ralphlavelle.net/2012/09/entity-framework-code-first-webconfig.html)

> Transformers
>   Right, well, if you are going to use web.config Entity Framework initialization, then you definitely want to use Web.config transformations. They just go together so well. Let's say you have a particular initialization strategy for your local dev environment - DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges, so you can just blow away your database every time it changes, whereupon it gets reseeded with some minimal data. That's what I do. And obviously you want the same thing in production. Only joking. That was a joke. You want MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, or maybe you want to switch initialization off completely. So how do you manage the change in the web.config. Manually?

Comment: codputer, it is good to clearly reply and even ask. Julie may be writing an article in a context (problem area/scope) that is not clear to you. Happens! Linking to the article and asking a question to clerify the confusion or to understand more, will be encouraging to all. 'Knowing More' is everyone's Curiosity. Happy Coding...

Comment: I totally agree - however the course is in video on Pluralsight, so I thought this was the best way to ask the question.  I then tweeted her, and she responded (see below).  Julie has my respect, but we all can make mistakes.  I believe this was one, I just had to make sure as I know she understands EF so well!

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood. I use DropCreateDatabaseAlways in my integration tests. Not in the repository! :)
Julie

Comment: I realize that DropCreateDatabaseAlways is likely not a good candidate for a production system :), so I can't mark this as an answer.  I'm looking for the order of operations.  As far as I can tell, this code would never execute the desired database initializer.

Comment: fair enough - i was thinking of a different sample. But I believe that you are misunderstanding (& misrepresenting) my guidance.  My m.o. is to turn off initialization in the base class that's used by the constrained dbcontext classes. In the course I also had a project that's responsible for doing the db initialization. It's context is aware of all of the entities & their relationships whereas the smaller contexts only know a subset. The context in that project does not inherit from the base class. So no conflict and therefore should be no question about one overriding the other.

Comment: Your right!  I missed that in the context that created the database, you did NOT inherit from Basecontext, but from DBContext!  I'm thinking that it's an easy miss, and I would recommend highlighting it in your video that the test method does NOT use the Basecontext.  Also, with EF6 perhaps an additional recommendation would be to push it into the config?  I had two employees review this, and we were all confused!